# Migrating to Typeahead 0.10+ with Hogan

Tags: javascript, template-engine, typeahead.js, hogan.js, twitter-typeahead

I have been using Typeahead 0.9.3 with Hogan 2 for a while and it was very straight forward to setup.

in 0.9.3 I did something like:

```
$('input.search-query').typeahead([
     {
         name:     "pages"
        ,local:    localSuggestions
        ,template: '<div class="tt-suggest-page">{{value}}</div>'
        ,engine:   Hogan
    }
]);
```

According to the [Migration Guide to 0.10](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/migration/0.10.0.md#precompiled-templates-are-now-required) "Precompiled Templates are Now Required", so in 0.10.3 I'm trying:

```
$('input.search-query').typeahead(null, {
     name:     "pages"
    ,source:   taSourceLocal.ttAdapter()
    ,templates: {
         suggestion: Hogan.compile('<div class="tt-suggest-page">{{value}}</div>')
     }
});
```

but it does not work.  I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

If there is another, minimalist template engine that can work I will consider it as well, but it has to be small.  I don't want to add a huge file like Handlebars or a whole library like Underscore.

any ideas?  TIA!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated by Jake Harding, [the solution for modern browsers](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/225#issuecomment-17489143) is like so:

```
var compiledTemplate = Hogan.compile('<div class="tt-suggest-page">{{value}}</div>');

$('input.search-query').typeahead(null, {
    // ...
    templates: {
        suggestion: compiledTemplate.render.bind(compiledTemplate);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, [Function.prototype.bind() is not supported by IE < 9](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Function.prototype.bind), so if you need to support older browsers that will not work.

The good news is that [as stated by Steve Pavarno](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Function.prototype.bind) you don't need a template engine anymore.  You can achieve the desired result by passing a function like so:

```
    // ...
    templates: {
        suggestion: function(data) { // data is an object as returned by suggestion engine
            return '<div class="tt-suggest-page">' + data.value + '</div>';
        };
    }
```

Comment: Note that the non-template engine version listed above is insecure if your data can contain HTML special characters (e.g. <>"'&) you would need to escape them.

Comment: There are a number of polyfills for bind, `$.proxy` of jQuery will also work for this use case.