# How to use typeahead with prefetch, hogan templating and multi key JSON file?

Tags: typeahead.js, hogan.js

I had implemented [hogan.js](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js) alongside [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) at these version states:

- `Hogan 2.0.0`
- `Typeahead 0.9.3`

I'm trying to upgrade to:

- `Hogan 3.0.2`
- `Typeahead 0.10.5`

This was my working code before the plugin upgrade:

**HTML**

```
<div class="course_lookup">
    <div class="demo">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Enter subject or subject area">
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function searchReadyFunction() {
    $('.course_lookup .typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'courses',
        valueKey: 'course_title',  
        prefetch: "/static/courses.json",
        template: [
            '<p class="course_area">{{course_area}}</p>',
            '<p class="course_title">{{course_title}}</p>',
            '<p class="course_description">{{course_description}}</p>'
        ].join(''),
        engine: Hogan  
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, selection) {
        var course_name = selection.course_title.toLowerCase();
        // ...
    });
}
```

**JSON**

My JSON data structure was:

```
[
{ "course_area": "Area01", "course_title": "title01", "course_description": "Description text 01", "tokens":["title01","Area01"]},
{ "course_area": "Area02", "course_title": "title02", "course_description": "Description text 02", "tokens":["title02", "Area02"]},
{ "course_area": "Area03", "course_title": "title03", "course_description": "Description text 03", "tokens":["title03","Area03"]},
{ "course_area": "Area02", "course_title": "title04", "course_description": "Description text 04", "tokens":["title04","Area02"]},
{ "course_area": "Area02", "course_title": "title05", "course_description": "Description text 05", "tokens":["title05","Area02"]},
{ "course_area": "Area04", "course_title": "title06", "course_description": "Description text 06", "tokens":["title06", "Area04"]},
{ "course_area": "Area05", "course_title": "title07", "course_description": "Description text 07", "tokens":["title07", "Area05"]}
]
```

**jsFiddle**

[jsFiddle shows original functionality achieved with older plugins](http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/5dpo4r4a).

The search would match the `token` values in the JSON file and return the results in the defined template with matching values ie `course_area`, `course_title` and `course_description`.

Upgrading `typeahead` causes this functionality not to work - there are no errors, it just doesn't work.

There is an official guide to upgrading typeahead here:

[Migrating to typeahead.js v0.10.0](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/migration/0.10.0.md)

And a similar question here:

[Migrating to Typeahead 0.10+ with Hogan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727534/migrating-to-typeahead-0-10-with-hogan)

My data is prefetched data however, and, as shown above, the function needs to return the values of three 'keys' from the JSON file.

The official [typeahead prefetch example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch) does not take into account such a scenario (where the source is not just a list, but comprised of `key:value` pairs), as far as I can tell.

How do I get the original functionality working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fiddle with working upgrade of Hogan and Typeahead :
http://jsfiddle.net/5dpo4r4a/41/

To make your code work, you need to use the new syntax for Typeahead.
The first argument is an option hash to configure behavior and the second is the suggestion engine config. You also need to declare the suggestion engine and initialize it.

```
var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.tokens.join(' ')); 
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '/static/courses.json'
});

dataSource.initialize();

function searchReadyFunction() {
  $('.course_lookup .typeahead').typeahead({
  },{
    name: 'courses',
    valueKey: 'course_title',
    template: suggestion: compiled_template.render.bind(compiled_template),
    source: dataSource.ttAdapter()
  }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, selection) {
    var course_name = selection.course_title.toLowerCase();
    // ...
  });
}
```

Let me know if you need more infos.

Comment: I have tested the fiddle and it seems to match only one token, not two, as shown in the original fiddle.  For example, it works on `title01` but not `area01`.

Comment: ok i updated the fiddle link and code. The trick is the datumTokenizer function, i just made it search on tokens instead of course_title and joined tokens as it is an array